# File Input does not upload file to MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For a project i've been trying to upload a file from my view to my controller action.
However, for some reason the action is reached but for the file i receive a null.

Here is my code:

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadSickNote")]
public ActionResult UploadSickNote(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Do something with file

    return RedirectToAction("SickNotes");
}
```

View:

```
<form Controller="Documents" Action="UploadSickNote" method="post">
    <div>
        <input id="sicknote-upload" name="UploadedSickNote" asp-for="UploadedSickNote" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
        <input id="sicknote-button-submit" type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have also tried using a viewmodel but with the same results.

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadSickNote")]
public ActionResult UploadSickNote(SickNotesViewModel vm)
{
    // Do something with file

    return RedirectToAction("SickNotes");
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SickNotesViewModel
{
    public List<SickNoteElement> SickNoteElements { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedSickNote { get; set; }
}
```

I am using asp.net mvc 5 (not asp.net core) and a bit of vue.js for view functionalities.
Any ideas or tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

You have to make sure that your input name matches your controller so

```
<input id="sicknote-upload" name="file" asp-for="UploadedSickNote" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

if with that doesnt work you could try also specifying the type of form you are sending

```
<form Controller="Documents" Action="UploadSickNote" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Fromform is for asp.net core. Which i am not allowed to use at the moment.My other actions that receive viewmodels all work without the use for fromform.

Comment: My bad i ll edit accordingly, you will have to change some things in your View then

Comment: The 2nd code fragment also works, i'll accept it as answer since it's prettier than what i found, thanks

Comment: Technically speaking they re the same, @Html.BeginForm is just a wrapper for the form tag, if you inspect the code you will see the same result

Comment: Yes but i do not like the look of the html wrappers in code so it's just personal preference :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after some more searching.
I now receive the file in my viewmodel by changing my view to this:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadSickNote", "Documents", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
            <div>
                <input id="sicknote-upload" name="UploadedSickNote" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
                <input id="sicknote-button-submit" type="submit"/>
            </div>
   }
```